# Не отображается иконка приложения

Tags: java, android, android-studio, icon, apk

указал в манифесте путь к новой иконке приложения:         `android:icon="@drawable/icon"` Затем сгенерировал апк и установил на другое устройство, но там иконка не отображается. Почему?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а что за иконка

Comment: можно больше инфыы?или саму иконку

Comment: Воспользуйтесь APK Analyser и посмотрите что за иконки в APK попадают, возможно это поможет понять откуда они берутся.

Comment: посмотрите, в Манифесте стоит ли параметр `android:roundIcon=""`. Если да, то уберите. Она используется в андроид 8+

Comment: @Jarvis_J помогло спасибо

Comment: добавил как ответ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В `AndroidManifest.xml` уберите атрибут `android:roundIcon="..."`. Она используется для устройств Андроид 8.+

В создании иконки через `New=>ImageAsset` она называется `Adaptive`. Обычная (для всех устройств) - `Legacy`. Можно отключить там.

Answer (score 2):

1)Убедитесь что ваша иконка формата `.png`

2)Проверьте что ваша иконка располагается по пути  `drawable/icon.png`

3)Сделайте очистку и пересбро делается это так 
 В Android Studio  наверху на панельку жмете `Build ->Clean Project`
 после очистки делаете пересбор `Build->Rebuild Project`

Comment: Не помогло. Картинку прикрепил. При отладке на устройство устанавливается приложение с моей иконкой. А при генерировании апк и установки апк на другое устройство, приложение устанавливается без моей иконки

Comment: залей код сюда проверим

Comment: Весь код приложения?

Comment: давай да посмотрим

Comment: или гит если есть

Comment: https://github.com/yalef/Xolostyak2.0

Answer (score 1):

Для иконок приложения существуют папки `mipmap`

```
android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
```

Поместите вашу иконку в эту папку, и проверьте.

Или сделайте лучше так:

Кликните на папку `Res` правой кнопкой мыши `New/ImageAsset` затем в поле `IconType` выберите `LauncherIcons`. Ниже, где поле `Path` укажите путь к вашей картинке, `Android Studio` сама сгенерирует нужные папки и нужные размеры иконки.

Comment: В любую из них? Просто мое изображение имеет только 1 вариант

Comment: Ну, это тоже не помогло

Comment: @Felay дополнил ответ

Comment: Почему я не могу выбрать свое Png - изображение? Студия даже не хочет открывать мою папку с изображениями в своем проводнике